# Getting a mega error in updating from 3.1

Tags: updates, updating

Firstly, I understand it's silly to leave a project go this out of date, but it was out of my hands. Secondly, there are many abandoned plugins in here, but I'm keen to the project updated then adjust the CMS to remove the ones that no longer work.

But my issue is this error log below after running `./craft update all`.  How best to find the specific package with the naming error?

See error log below:

```
Performing update with Composer...error: Unknown package has no name defined...
```

Then proceeds to output an object with every package on the project, that is too long for me to include in this ticket.

[image: error screen]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're running into a similar issue to [this one](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/36551/unknown-package-has-no-name-defined-composer-error-on-upgrade).

The problem is likely caused by incompatibilities between Composer 1 and 2 (as in, the project's dependencies were initially installed using Composer 1, and now you're likely using Composer 2).

As suggested in the above thread, you might be able to resolve by following the below steps:

1. Delete the `vendor` folder and the `composer.lock` file
2. Run `composer install`
3. Run `./craft update all`